# Testing for linear independence using determinants?

Tags: linear-algebra

My book demonstrates how to test whether a set of vectors ***S*** = {**v**<sub>1</sub>, **v**<sub>2</sub>, **v**<sub>3</sub>} is linearly independent by writing c<sub>1</sub>**v**<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub>**v**<sub>2</sub> + c<sub>3</sub>**v**<sub>3</sub> = **0**, equating corresponding components to form a system of linear equations, and then reducing the augmented matrix of this system using Gauss-Jordan elimination.

My question is, couldn't you just evaluate the determinant of the matrix rather than using elimination? Couldn't you say that if the determinant is nonzero, the system has only the trivial solution and therefore ***S*** is independent; and if it's zero, the system has infinitely many solutions (since we know it can't have no solutions as it has at least the trivial solution) and ***S*** is therefore dependent? Or do you have to use Gaussian elimination?

Comment: Determinants absolutely work! In linear algebra, there are often multiple ways of solving a problem. Unless your teacher makes use a particular method, you can use whichever method you find easiest. (Incidentally, for large matrices, Gaussian elimination is much faster than computing determinants.)

Comment: If the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} \mid & \mid & \mid \\ \mathbf v_1 & \mathbf v_2 & \mathbf v_3 \\ \mid & \mid & \mid \end{bmatrix}$ is **square**, then yes, you could instead use the determinant to check for linear indepedence.

Comment: @eepperly16 For large matrices, the standard way to compute determinants is with the same row reduction you use to do Gaussian elimination, so the times are essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

[Determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) is defined only for square matrices. So the answer to your question depends on what *vector space* are the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ in.

For instance, if $v_1=v_2=v_3=(1,1)^T$, what matrix do you get?

---

By the way, $\bf{S}$ is a *set*, not a matrix. One gets a matrix by making the columns as $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$.